pydev debug server shows error that doesn't apply
I am learning how to use PyDev Remote Debugging. I am encountering an erroneous error message.
I apply Remote Debugging to a HelloWorld python program on a remote machine that consists of:
#This program prints Hello, world!
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('192.168.1.31')
print('Hello, world!')
The IP address is that of the machine running Eclipse/PyDev
On Eclipse I have a project with the following program:
#This program prints Hello, world!
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace()
print('Hello, world!')
I start the Debug Server on Eclipse and set a breakpoint at the print statement. The debug server then reports:
pydev debugger: Trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: /home/dnessett/eclipse-workspace/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.py (will have no effect).
However, when I run the program on the remote machine, the breakpoint (green highlighting) shows up and when I step over the breakpoint, the remote execution completes as expected.

As an aside, I don't know why 'import pydevd' is showing an unresolved reference. I would appreciate any help fixing that as well.

Is this file in a project in the workspace? Is it at the location that's in the error message?

By this file, do you mean HelloWorld.py? Yes, it is in a project in the workspace.

You can always append to your original post, and you don't suppose this is related to there being a space in the filesystem location?

I don't know the answer to the "space in the filesystem location" question. Perhaps that is the problem.

Your project's name is "Hello World" in the second image, but there's no space in the location in the error message.

I have deleted the image that showed the directory structure on the Eclipse machine, since I incorrectly screenshot that structure on my Macintosh. I have posted a corrected image in a comment to the Answer provided below. The project structure does not contain any files with spaces in their names. Sorry for the confusion.

Related to the stopping issue, it's hard to diagnose without further information:
Can you provide:

Where's the code in the remote machine (where python is running)
Where's the code in the local machine (where you're running Eclipse/PyDev)

As a note, adding pydevd.settrace will make the program pause there even without a breakpoint.
My guess is that you need to set the Path Mapping in the to make it work as you intend in Preferences > PyDev > Debug > Path Mappings. Search for "Path Mapping" in https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html for more information.
Related to:

As an aside, I don't know why 'import pydevd' is showing an unresolved reference. I would appreciate any help fixing that as well.

The fact that pydevd doesn't appear there is because you probably don't have it installed in your python environment (usually I just ignore it as Eclipse will add it automatically when you run, although the message is there to know that it'll fail if you run it out of Eclipse/PyDev).

I have created an image that presents the information you requested - https://imgur.com/a/yLRJ1kQ. The first part shows the project structure on the Eclipse machine, the second shows the Python directory structure on the remote machine, and the final part shows the Eclipse window. I have deleted the original image in my comments to the original post, since I incorrectly grabbed the wrong image of the directory structure (I grabbed that from my Macintosh, not from my two Linux machines). The images shown here are correct.

I tried adding Path Mappings - [
{
"localRoot": "/",
"remoteRoot": "/"
}
]
This did not work. I thought it might not since the Eclipse machine is Linux Mint 21.3 and the remote python machine is Linux Mint 21.1

That mapping really does nothing. What you want is say that localRoot is /home/user/eclipse-workspace and remoteRoot is /home/user/PythonProjects. Alternatively, you could just have the sources in the same places in both machines, then the path mapping wouldn't be needed.

i.e.: the path mapping is just a way to map the paths from one machine to another.

Your clarification about the values of localRoot and remoteRoot solved the problem. I interpreted the write up at https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html when it referred to "root" to mean the two respective file system roots, not the source roots to the python code. Thanks for your help.
